# CVS-SVN - pointing at the same files

Tags: svn, cvs

I'm currently involved in a team project via CVS.  I want to isolate my team so I decided to setup an SVN repository locally wherein my team could check-in using SVN and I would be the only one with access to both CVS and SVN.

This is what I plan to do:

1. Check out from CVS
2. Check into SVN the files from CVS
3. My devs works on SVN
4. I update SVN to get changes from the devs
5. Perform conflict resolution with CVS
6. Commit merged source code

My question is: Is it possible to have a single folder on my local drive having both CVS and SVN pointing to it?